# How to login into Wiki from android?

Tags: android, http-post, mediawiki-api

I'm using the MediaWiki api to login into it, I'm able to get token for first time.

Step 1: get token (post method).

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=login&lgname=username&lgpassword=password&format=json
```

Step 2: copy the token and append it to below link it replies is whether it was successful or not. (post method).

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=login&lgname=username&lgpassword=password&format=json&lgtoken=token
```

But for me it's replying Token required, yet I have attached the token. When I tried using the poster plug-in in Firefox, it worked fine.

Comment: Are you really sending a password inside your url ???

Comment: yeah check out this doc 
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?

Comment: Are you sending the cookies the first request set with the second request? And if you're using POST, you should probably send the parameters in the POST body. One reason is that URLs of requests tend to be logged.

Comment: @svick NO i'm not sending cookies as header ,even i think this is the problem of cookie, Can u pleas let me know what to send in cookie , i have session ID .

Comment: Have you considered using an API library, e.g. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Java